# Print a value from a fact in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

Let's say I have these facts:

```
champion(Real_Madrid).
second_place(Atl).
```

How do I print the "Real_Madrid" string value from a query in Prolog so I can say for example:

Champions(Something).

Real_Madrid

Any way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Prolog, atoms need quotes if they start by an upper-case letter so that they're not confused with variables.

Here, you could write:

```
champion('Real Madrid').
second_place('Atl').
```

Then the simple query:

```
?- champion(Something).
```

would print the required bindings:

```
Something = 'Real Madrid'.
```

If needed, you can find more information about Prolog syntax [here](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse2).

Comment: Great, that was all I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will need a variable that will print that value for you.

In Prolog, variables start with upper-case.

So if you execute any query like:

`champion(X).` or `champion(Something).` or `champion(Winner).` etc, the result would be the same and it would be `X=Real Madrid` or `Something=Real Madrid` or `Winner=Real Madrid` etc.

The name of the variable could be anything. Even 'Loser' and the result would be the same.

*Don't forget the period (`.`) at the end of the query you execute*