# Member and List in prolog?

Tags: list, prolog, member

I am trying to write a code which assign a color to a state. There are 5 states(Tn, Ms, Al, Ga, Fl) that I want to assign a color to each. I have to use only three colors, and no two states which share a border can have the same color.
I wrote this code:

```
states(T, M, A, G, F) :-
  member(T, [Green, White, Red]),
  member(M, [Green, White, Red]),
  member(A, [Green, White, Red]),
  member(G, [Green, White, Red]),
  member(F, [Green, White, Red]),
  T = F,
  G = M.
```

When I test my code I get a weird output! For example if I use this code:

```
states(T,M,A,G,F), write(['TN', T, ' MS', M, ' AL', A, ' GA', G, ' FL', F]).
```

I get a bunch of unifier numbers! How can I assign colors to states?
What I was trying to do here was that I am saying in my code that Tn and Fl should have same color, and Ga and Mi also should have same color! But it seems I am doing it wrong. Where am I doing wrong? I do not get any color as output! How to assign colors to States?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You do know that `Green`, `White`, and `Red` are all variables, right? That would be your issue. Use lower case first letter (like `green`) or use single quotes (like `'Green'`) to get atoms. Visit your local friendly Prolog manual for details. :)

Comment: Aww I knew it should be a stupid mistake! lol I always do it! Thank you so much luker for your fantastic hint. I got it to work. :)

Comment: Please, Lurker, just add your tip as an answer. ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Print a value from a fact in Prolog?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23644500/print-a-value-from-a-fact-in-prolog)